# Windows CMD to list files from map drive

Tags: cmd, command-line, command-prompt

How to list all files from map drive using cmd command?
Path :

```
Z: \\Server\folder1\data
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you mean ```dir /s \\server\folder1\data```?

Comment: … or maybe `dir /b /s /a-d z:\ ` or `where.exe /r z:\ *`